# Seeking to every 30th frame in .mp4 file with ffmpeg

Tags: c, ffmpeg, decode

I'm trying to seek to every 30th frame and read motion vectors from packets.

```c
// Move the video 1 frame
av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, &pkt);
if (pkt.stream_index == video_stream_idx)
    ret = decode_packet(&pkt);
av_packet_unref(&pkt);

// Read motion vectors until end of video
while (av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, &pkt) >= 0) {
    if (pkt.stream_index == video_stream_idx)
        ret = decode_packet(&pkt);

    // Find packet frame
    int pcktPts = av_rescale_q(pkt.pts,
            fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream_idx]->time_base,
            fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream_idx]->codec->time_base);
    pcktPts = (pcktPts/video_dec_ctx->ticks_per_frame);

    // Find target position from packet (30 frames ahead)
    int target = (pcktPts+30) *
                 (fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream_idx]->time_base.den /
                  fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream_idx]->time_base.num) /
                 (fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream_idx]->codec->time_base.den /
                  fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream_idx]->codec->time_base.num )*
                 video_dec_ctx->ticks_per_frame;

    // Seek to 30 frames ahead
    avformat_seek_file(fmt_ctx, video_stream_idx, 0, target, target, AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY);

    av_packet_unref(&pkt);
    if (ret < 0)
        break;
}
```

Running through this, it runs well at first, but starts to hang at around the 6th or 7th frame analyzed. Here's my output of what frame I'm decoding:

```
1
31
61
92
123
155
187
220
237
237
237
...
```

where it just stalls on frame 237. So a few things are wrong: the program is hanging, and I'm not increasing by 30 frames every time, but by 30 + some random number. I must be using some function wrong. This is specifically for .mp4 files.

Essentially, I want to read motion vectors from every frame following an I-frame. My entire program is here:

```c
#include <libavutil/motion_vector.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>

static AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx = NULL;
static AVCodecContext *video_dec_ctx = NULL;
static AVStream *video_stream = NULL;
static const char *src_filename = NULL;

static int video_stream_idx = -1;
static AVFrame *frame = NULL;
static int video_frame_count = 0;

static int decode_packet(const AVPacket *pkt)
{
    char szFileName[255] = {0};
    FILE *file = NULL;
    int ret = avcodec_send_packet(video_dec_ctx, pkt);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while sending a packet to the decoder: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        return ret;
    }

    while (ret >= 0)  {
        ret = avcodec_receive_frame(video_dec_ctx, frame);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
            break;
        } else if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while receiving a frame from the decoder: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
            return ret;
        }

        if (ret >= 0) {
            int i;
            AVFrameSideData *sd;
            video_frame_count++;
            sprintf(szFileName, "./mv/frame%d.txt", video_frame_count);
            file = fopen(szFileName, "w");
            sd = av_frame_get_side_data(frame, AV_FRAME_DATA_MOTION_VECTORS);
            if (sd) {
                const AVMotionVector *mvs = (const AVMotionVector *)sd->data;
                for (i = 0; i < sd->size / sizeof(*mvs); i++) {
                    const AVMotionVector *mv = &mvs[i];
                    fprintf(file, "%4d %4d %4d %4d\n",
                        abs(mv->motion_x),
                        abs(mv->motion_y),
                        abs(mv->src_x - mv->dst_x),
                        abs(mv->src_y - mv->dst_y));
                }
            }
            fclose(file);
            av_frame_unref(frame);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

static int open_codec_context(AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx, enum AVMediaType type)
{
    int ret;
    AVStream *st;
    AVCodecContext *dec_ctx = NULL;
    AVCodec *dec = NULL;
    AVDictionary *opts = NULL;

    ret = av_find_best_stream(fmt_ctx, type, -1, -1, &dec, 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find %s stream in input file '%s'\n",
                av_get_media_type_string(type), src_filename);
        return ret;
    } else {
        int stream_idx = ret;
        st = fmt_ctx->streams[stream_idx];

        dec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(dec);
        if (!dec_ctx) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate codec\n");
            return AVERROR(EINVAL);
        }

        ret = avcodec_parameters_to_context(dec_ctx, st->codecpar);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy codec parameters to codec context\n");
            return ret;
        }

        // Initialize video decoder
        av_dict_set(&opts, "flags2", "+export_mvs", 0);
        if ((ret = avcodec_open2(dec_ctx, dec, &opts)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s codec\n",
                    av_get_media_type_string(type));
            return ret;
        }

        video_stream_idx = stream_idx;
        video_stream = fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream_idx];
        video_dec_ctx = dec_ctx;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ret = 0;
    AVPacket pkt = { 0 };

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <video>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    src_filename = argv[1];

    if (avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, src_filename, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open source file %s\n", src_filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (avformat_find_stream_info(fmt_ctx, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find stream information\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    open_codec_context(fmt_ctx, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
    av_dump_format(fmt_ctx, 0, src_filename, 0);

    if (!video_stream) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find video stream in the input, aborting\n");
        ret = 1;
        goto end;
    }

    frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate frame\n");
        ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        goto end;
    }

    // Move the video 1 frame
    av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, &pkt);
    if (pkt.stream_index == video_stream_idx)
        ret = decode_packet(&pkt);
    av_packet_unref(&pkt);

    // Read motion vectors until end of video
    while (av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, &pkt) >= 0) {
        if (pkt.stream_index == video_stream_idx)
            ret = decode_packet(&pkt);

        int pcktPts = av_rescale_q(pkt.pts,
                fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream_idx]->time_base,
                fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream_idx]->codec->time_base);
        pcktPts = (pcktPts/video_dec_ctx->ticks_per_frame);

        int target = (pcktPts+30) *
                     (fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream_idx]->time_base.den /
                      fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream_idx]->time_base.num) /
                     (fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream_idx]->codec->time_base.den /
                      fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream_idx]->codec->time_base.num )*
                     video_dec_ctx->ticks_per_frame;

        avformat_seek_file(fmt_ctx, video_stream_idx, 0, target, target, AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY);

        av_packet_unref(&pkt);
        if (ret < 0)
            break;
    }

    // Flush cached frames
    decode_packet(NULL);
    fprintf(stderr, "Finished decoding.\n\n");

end:
    avcodec_free_context(&video_dec_ctx);
    avformat_close_input(&fmt_ctx);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    return ret < 0;
}
```